# Before login how to pass foreign key during registration

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have two tables: `usertype` and `users`.

User Type is entered and assigned an ID in the `usertype` table.

When a user registers, they will select the type of account from a dropdown list.

Please help me figure out how to use the ID of `usertype` as a foreign key into `user` table.

Comment: Can we have some code ?

Comment: The documentation clearly shows you how to do this... https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: i have written these methods in both table but ids are not moving foreign key constraints is showed when user try to submit his data for registration

Comment: Can you please provide us with the controller functions and possibly the used views?